# Forcing an "On demand" VPN in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa, vpn

1. Is it possible to force a vpn connection always and not an "on demand"
2. also on demand requires domains to be added in the configuration file..what if the domains keep changing? why is it designed this way i.e. only for some domains? what if i need a vpn for all domains and dont want to add list of several available domains like .ru, .in?
   Any help would be appreciable..

Comment: You can accept any of the answers that were useful to you so that others can easily get the answers

Answer (score 2):

I use the following payload in my configuration profile and it works in both iOS 6 and 7 also.

It will establish VPN connection for any network request

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>OnDemandMatchDomainsAlways</key>
            <array>
                <string>*</string>                        
            </array>
            <key>OnDemandMatchDomainsNever</key>
            <array/>
            <key>OnDemandMatchDomainsOnRetry</key>
            <array/>
            <key>OnDemandRules</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Action</key>
                    <string>Connect</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in ios7 only available on ios5 and prior